# Akka threads constant in futex_ state -- Is this normal?

Tags: scala, akka

I have an Akka program with threads that are spending most of their time in the `futex_` state.

This is from an Akka program that isn't doing much. I am not familiar with the internals of Akka, so I'm not sure if this is normal or not.

```
F S   UID    PID   PPID    LWP  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY        TIME CMD
4 S     1     19      0     19  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
5 S     1     19      0     25  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:04 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     26  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     27  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     28  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     29  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     30  1  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:12 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     31  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:04 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     32  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     33  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     43  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:02 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     44  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     45  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     46  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:01 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     47  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:02 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     50  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     53  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:01 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0     60  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:03 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0    121  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0    122  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:01 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0    123  0  80   0 - 1149556 ep_pol ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0    282  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0    283  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0    284  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0    285  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0    295  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:01 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0    383  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0    433  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:01 /usr/bin/java
1 S     1     19      0   1109  0  80   0 - 1149556 futex_ ?        0:00 /usr/bin/java
```

Checking the syscalls, there are a ton of timed out futex calls constantly happening. Here's a snippet from just a fraction of a second:

```
[pid    43] futex(0x7f36266dfc28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid    43] futex(0x7f36266dfc54, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1, {tv_sec=14532, tv_nsec=950443844}, 0xffffffff <unfinished ...>
[pid    47] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid    47] futex(0x7f3626f8ab28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid    47] futex(0x7f3626f8ab54, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1, {tv_sec=14532, tv_nsec=954449564}, 0xffffffff <unfinished ...>
[pid    33] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid    33] futex(0x7f3624a11128, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid    33] futex(0x7f3624a11154, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1, {tv_sec=14532, tv_nsec=998037087}, 0xffffffff <unfinished ...>
[pid    43] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid    43] futex(0x7f36266dfc28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid    43] futex(0x7f36266dfc54, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1, {tv_sec=14532, tv_nsec=960733704}, 0xffffffff <unfinished ...>
[pid    47] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid    47] futex(0x7f3626f8ab28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid    47] futex(0x7f3626f8ab54, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1, {tv_sec=14532, tv_nsec=964665830}, 0xffffffff <unfinished ...>
[pid    43] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid    43] futex(0x7f36266dfc28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid    43] futex(0x7f36266dfc54, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1, {tv_sec=14532, tv_nsec=971001771}, 0xffffffff <unfinished ...>
[pid    47] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid    47] futex(0x7f3626f8ab28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid    47] futex(0x7f3626f8ab54, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1, {tv_sec=14532, tv_nsec=973981797}, 0xffffffff <unfinished ...>
[pid    43] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid    43] futex(0x7f36266dfc28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid    43] futex(0x7f36266dfc54, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1, {tv_sec=14532, tv_nsec=980553240}, 0xffffffff <unfinished ...>
[pid    47] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

My theory is that this may be the Akka actors rapidly checking to see if there's any new work for them to do, but I am seeking confirmation if that is a valid theory. Thank you!

Comment: Can you also gather Java-level stacktraces using `jstack <pid>`? That will give better information. In any case, Akka uses the JDK ForkJoinPool as a pool of threads. When there's isn't enough work the threads might poll for work for a bit and are then parked until more work is available. I haven't looked it up, but I guess the parking is implemented using futexes in the JVM. When there's enough work this shouldn't happen as often as the threads just stay alive.

Comment: In a common scenario it is expected that some threads park and unpark frequently. The reason is that when the system is not at full load, there will be at least one idle thread in the pool. In that case, as soon as a message is sent to an actor that is waiting for messages, the mailbox of this actor is scheduled to be processed. That will usually reactivate (unpark) another thread for the other actor. The thread that ran the sending actor, on the other hand, might be idle after having processed the sending actor's mailbox and might go to sleep itself.

Comment: So, you might see a ping-pong of two threads getting woken up in turns. This is regular behavior. You should make sure that you don't overprovision threads, though, otherwise, the pool will regularly unpark or spawn up new threads when all cores are already busy.